# Well pump exceeds normal pressure

Tags: pump, well-pump

The pressure gauge on our pump (which brings in water from our well) seems to be having troubles.  The gauge is not supposed to go above 45.  Usually, when the gauge reads 40 the pump will turn off.

Now, it is not causing the pump to turn off and will keep increasing pressure, according to the gauge.  Does this seem to be a problem with the gauge, the pump, the regulation switch or the tank?  I am not sure where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like the switch is failing. You may have a dangerous situation there.  Be careful.

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be most likely a faulty pressure switch.

Start there.

The job of the pressure switch is to turn on when the water pressure is low, and turn off when it is high enough - this is most commonly a 20 PSI range (ie, 20-40, 30-50 or 40-60 PSI.)

The pump is evidently working.

The pressure gauge is evidently working unless you see some other behavior that suggests otherwise, such as a non-zero pressure when you drain the system.

A tank problem would not cause uncontrolled pressure rise. The most common tank problem (failed bladder/waterlogging) would cause abrupt pressure rise and the pressure switch would cut off very quickly.

Unless you have gremlins that would have altered the adjustment of your pressure switch, all reported symptoms point to switch failure. Start with replacing it, should be in stock at most any hardware store.

Comment: I have had pressure switches fail usually on the coldest day of the year but @Ecnerwal is giving great info and advice

Comment: Thank you!  We now have a place to start. I really do appreciate the advice.